# How to add a dynamically generated file to my ear archive?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, groovy, build

Basically, we have an ear archive that has multiple dependencies. In those dependencies, we plan on filling the manifest or some properties file with multiple properties:

- build timestamp
- buildnumber (from CI server)
- groupId
- artifactId
- version

This should already be possible for individual artifacts that are built by our CI server, and this is also not really the problem I'm having.

---

Now I use maven for building my **ear** archive, with the maven-ear-plugin. My idea was to just use a groovy script (executed by gmaven-plus) that will read all the jar archives, and fetch the manifest. Then I can rewrite the manifest of the ear archive, or write my own properties file that contains the info I want.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import java.util.jar.JarFile

def path = "target/${project.name}-${project.version}"
def artifactDir = new File(path)
def output = new File("$path/META-INF/build-info.properties")

def lines = []

artifactDir.listFiles().each { file->
    if (file.isFile() && (file.name.endsWith(".war") || file.name.endsWith(".jar"))) {
        def jar = new JarFile(file)
        def manifest = jar.manifest
        println "processing: $file.name"
        println manifest.mainAttributes
        println jar.properties
        manifest.mainAttributes.keySet().each { attrKey->
            def val = manifest.mainAttributes.getValue(attrKey.toString())
            lines << "$file.name.$attrKey=$val"
        }
    }
}

FileUtils.writeLines(output, lines as Collection<?>
```

)

This script works fine, and will write the `build-info.properties` file with all the info I'd like to be in there.

This is the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-manifest</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <scripts>
            <script>file:///${project.basedir}/src/main/gmaven/create-manifest.groovy</script>
        </scripts>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Of course, you'll already notice what's wrong with this: the `package`phase is too late, `prepare-package` is too early, because the ear plugin has not yet copied the dependencies I'm scanning.

---

### Conclusion

Well, the obvious thing to do would be to unzip the ear produced, and then add the file manually, then zip it again. But that seems pretty dirty to me, and I was wondering whether there is no cleaner way to do this?

Perhaps by leverageing gradle, or some option of the maven-ear-plugin I have not yet discovered? Or just in general, how would you tackle the specific problem I am facing here?

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the maven possibilities..like the configuration for [the archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) which means you can use a configuration like this for the maven-jar-plugin:

```xml
   <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
              <index>true</index>
              <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
              </manifest>
              <manifestEntries>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
              </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This can also be used for maven-war-plugin, maven-ejb-plugin and for maven-ear-plugin as well...See the [docs for maven-ear-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html) see `archive` entry.

The buildnumber from your CI solution (for example Jenkins) has an env variable `BUILD_NUMBER` which you can use as well...

Full example how a corporate pom can look like [take a look here](https://github.com/khmarbaise/smpp/blob/master/pom.xml).

**Update:**

What i missed is that you can use filtering to create such file. Put a file into `src/main/resources`  with the following content:

```
groupId=${project.groupId}
artifactId=${project.artifactId}
version=${project.version}
```

Define the following as part of your pom file:

...
      
        src/main/resources
        true

Furthermore this will package the above file into your ear/war/jar file.

Apart from that a file which contains already the above information can be found in earchive `META-INF/groupId/artifactId/pom.properties` which contains the above. Not the build number and build time...

The build time can be used by using the following:

```xml
 <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <buildTime>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildTime>
              <buildNumber>${env.BUILDNUMBER}</buildNumber>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

`${env.BUILDNUMBER}` is of course a refererence to bamboos variables which contains such information.

Comment: I use maven daily, however I did not find anything that does what I actually needed. That's why I attempted to find my own solution. Thanks i'll check that plugin out.

Comment: I just found out a way I can make it work with the script. Since we use bamboo, I can just register the file I created as a bamboo artifact, and then I can use it later. However, I'd still like to know how to do it in maven.

Comment: Every plugin like [maven-ejb-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/ejb-mojo.html#archive), [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#archive) and so on...Best is to make a corporate pom which contains the appropriate configuration via pluginManagement and that's it...

Comment: This looks very viable, but how am I going to get entries in the ear manifest that are inside the manifests of its dependencies? Maybe that's not clear from my question though. I have an ear that contains multiple wars, and I'd like to combine all these manifests (or at least certain entries) in the ear manifest as I'm doing with the script. E.g. assume the ear has a project with artifactId ´foobar´, then i'd want to put `foobar.version=${foobar.artifact.version}` in the manifest of the ear archive.

Comment: Why are you appending all entries of those manifest files into the EAR one which does not make sense nor will it behave correct,cause you will get duplicate entries...All jar files which are being produces should be correct configured. Apart from that your ear file contains the pom.xml file in META-INF folder...

Comment: You're correct, that is because we are mainly interested in the build timestamp and the buildnumber provided by our CI, which we can only get from the actual artifacts as far as I know. In short, we'd like to know exactly what build from our CI server is running and when it was built.

In my script, I prefix every entry of the manifest with the artifactId, thus avoiding duplicates.